# Doctrine2 many-to-many association using sub entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have `Hotel` entity with many-to-many relationship with an entity `Airport` through entity `Distanсe`

```
/**
 *
 * @Table(name="Hotel")
 * @Entity
 */
class Hotel
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="hotel_id", type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $hotel_id;

}


/**
 *
 * @Table(name="Airport")
 * @Entity
 */
class Airport
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="airport_id", type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $airport_id;

}
```

I do not know how to describe the association to the `Distance` class?

```
/**
 *
 * @Table(name="Distance")
 * @Entity
 */
class Distance
{

    private $airport_id;

    private $hotel_id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="distance", type="integer")
     *
     */
    private $distance;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP-Doctrine2: Items - Shops - ItemsAtShops - how to conveniently implement using Doctrine2? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185598/php-doctrine2-items-shops-itemsatshops-how-to-conveniently-implement-using)